# Does Razor support html fragments flushing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, razor

I just read this [interesting post](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2014/async-fragments-rediscovering-progressive-html-rendering-with-marko/) on perf calendar written by Patrick Steel-Idem.
The post basically describes a way of flushing html fragments to browser, in order to improve the perceived loading time; it shows, as by sending the browser little fragments of the html, it can start its elaboration, and further requests earlier.
In his example Patrick works with nodejs, and uses Marko as templating engine.

My question is: since I have a completely different stack (asp.net mvc5) do you know a way to achieve the same results using Razor as templating engine? Can you point me to the right resources?

Thanks

Comment: You mean something like this? http://nikcodes.com/2014/03/04/flushing-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: And as a follow up - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekCourtesyFlushToFlushBuffersEarlierAndOptimizeTimeToFirstByte.aspx

Comment: Those links about flushing are good, but to me it feels a bit too much like putting display logic in the controller. I feel that it belongs in the view and can be done cleanly with AJAX. [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion... the link you provided gave me a background... however, @AndyNichols solution seems simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Evans and Andy Nichols point out there is isn't anything built into Razor to support this but there are workarounds.

However MVC 6 has a new keyword `FlushAsync()` to address this requirement.

`@await FlushAsync()`