# How to speed up page rendering in Asp.Net Core MVC with large MySql query?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core

I have about 20k products in a Xampp local DB. I created an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC project. I then created the products model with Scaffold-DbContext. I also created the regular views and controller with the VS Studio built in Add Controller for the Index, Create, etc... Everything works as expected but Index page only renders after many seconds. As if all data needed to be downloaded from the db before rendering started on the first rows.

Is there a way to have the page start loading the first rows as the subsequent rows keep being fetched/downloaded?

MySql workbench fetch the same data:
09:10:52    SELECT * FROM crm.products LIMIT 0, 50000   19200 row(s) returned   0.016 sec / 0.031 sec

```
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly crmContext _context;

        public ProductsController(crmContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Products
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Products.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
```

Products model

```
    public partial class Products
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateEntered { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
        public int? ModifiedUserId { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte? Deleted { get; set; }
        public int? AssignedUserId { get; set; }
        public string Maincode { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
        public decimal? CostUsdollar { get; set; }
        public int? CurrencyId { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
        public decimal? PriceUsdollar { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int? ContactId { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
        public int? ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Forgot to add I use MySql.Data and `            services.AddDbContext<suitecrmContext>(options => 
                options.UseMySQL(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("XamppConnection")));`

Comment: We can't tell you if you've coded something that would cause a performance problem without seeing all your code. What you can do is actually profile things and narrow down which part is taking so long.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616635/does-razor-support-html-fragments-flushing may be of interest.

Comment: I hesitated to post all my code since I am not sure which part(s) would be helpful. Which parts do you need to see? Controller, view, connections? I am quite new to this so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Are you rendering 19,200 rows on one web page? That doesn't seem suitable for a user interface. What sense can anyone make of that many rows on a single page?

Comment: @user10405895 It's up to you to determine which piece of code is actually slow. You can read the directions at [MCVE] to assist in narrowing it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As if all data needed to be downloaded from the db before rendering
>   started on the first rows.

That's exactly what it's doing and what's it's meant to be.

As @Nick.McDermaid pointed out, there are hardly any reason for you to display 20k rows to the user in a single page.

Think about using some [paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 0):

If it's being returned to the view to be modified/displayed in razor then there probably isn't much you can do because the View won't be served to the client until after all the Server-side processing is complete.

If it doesn't matter how the data is sent to the view then you could always do an Ajax request?

Answer (score -1):

In case of "Long rendering" or "Long waiting time" you can do some stuff to trick the user. If he perceive that everything is moving fast then you're ok ( if that's your case).

This is what I suggest do if you REALLY need to display 20k of rows. (Remember this will not be usable for an user).

1. You can do some Ajax request so you'll page will render and then the content.
2. Most tables components use a set of properties like (dataToDisplay, currentPage, AmountPerPage, Total, etc.. etc...). You can do some kind of change to load the first 200 (page 1) and keep fetching data until you reach page 10. If you do this in an ajax way it will "feel quick".

Again. If your application will be used for humans, I think it would be better to find a another approach to display the information.

You can try to create charts, parse the information, create groups or whatever to create a more usable application. Have a look to [Data visualization](https://www.tableau.com/learn/articles/data-visualization)

Comment: There isn't a viable reason for displaying 20K rows.

Comment: @mason I agree too. I just edited the post to make the OP think about other things to do.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments/help. I was going to start pagination but since the end user was used to have a "list" of all items in front of him, my own thought process was to try and present it in the same fashion. Now I know that pagination makes more sense. I will change the interface to reflect that.

Comment: @user10405895 Mark a correct answer if you find one.